# Hide div through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide a div with jQuery...

But i am confused that what is the best way to do this?

1. I can hide the div by changing its css display property to none.

   ```
   $("#header-link1").click(function(){
     $("#header2").css({
       'display': 'none'
     });
   }
   ```

   or,
2. I can do the same thing with jQuery hide() function.

   ```
   $("#header-link1").click(function(){
     $("#header2").hide();
   }
   ```

Any suggestions what is the best way and why?

Comment: Neither is "better", they are just different.

Comment: @Quentin No, they are the same.

Comment: But someone told me that css executes faster... Is that true?

Comment: @ShazZ - It should be the same performance wise. The only thing hide() does different is pick up the original display setting to allow it to restore later on.

Comment: If I were you, I would go with `.hide()`. Although its just a wrapper for `display:none`, they must have had a good reason to write it. And it definitely makes code more readable.

Comment: Another option could be to use classes. Something like `$('#header2').addClass('hide');` and `$('#header2').removeClass('hide');`. You can adapt your `hide` class after your needs. I would still go with `$.hide()` and `$.show()` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You should use method 2** since if you want to `show()` it again, it will take care of setting the `display` to the correct value, meaning `inline` for inline elements and `block` for block elements, whereas if you use method 1 you will have to choose for yourself what is the correct `display` even tho' usually it is `block`.

Comment: this is nice, but can be a bit frustrating. Say you have an inline element displayed as block (`<a class="block">`). After you apply `hide` and then `show` the element has an inline style (although you specified it to be as `block` in the css)

Comment: +1 - This is also the cleanest way of writing it. Making it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the jQuery API for .hide() (http://api.jquery.com/hide/) you will notice that .hide() utilizes the css display attribute as its method to hide a page element. Thus, they serve the exact same purpose, but one is just a bit cleaner.

I personally would go with $("#div").hide() because it is much cleaner and keeps your code that much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, technically. If you see the source code of jQuery, this is what happens when you call hide():

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L66

There are two differences:

1. There is support for animation in `hide()`
2. There is a data parameter set called 'olddisplay', so you can restore it at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

try this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#header-link1").click(function(){
    $("#header2").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```